# Как связать form с input

Tags: html

Как связать `form` с `input type="submit"` если `input type="submit"` находиться вне тега `form`

```html
<form>
    <input type="text">
</form>

<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Атрибут form](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/form)** - Связывает поле с формой по её идентификатору.

```
<input type="<тип>" form="<идентификатор>">
<form id="<идентификатор>">...</form>
Значения
```